# Copying assets referenced in css files

Tags: node.js, gulp

Is there a way, using Gulp, to copy assets, like images and fonts, referenced in CSS files to a specific directory?

For example, when bundling Bootstrap 3 along with the rest of my CSS files, I need the fonts to be copied and their URLs to be rebased to the new directory.

I could do this using Webpack and a combination of loaders (`style-loader`, `css-loader`, `url-loader` and `file-loader`), but for this project I need to use nothing other than Gulp and its plugins.

Edit: I'm going to try and be more clear.

I'm going to use the Bootstrap 3 example again: its CSS file references the fonts it uses through `url()`. What I need to do is to see what fonts are referenced in these `url()`,  copy them to my `/public/` directory, and finally, rebase these `url()` so the fonts can properly be served.

Comment: The first part of your question sounds like you need to parse the CSS, build a list of referenced files from that, and then work with that list (maybe using it for your `gulp.src`?). But the second part of your question makes it sound like you need something pretty significantly different: to 1) copy files from a known directory and 2) run through some CSS files and adjust paths to the match compiled project's folder structure. // Can you say more about exactly what you need to do?

Comment: Added more information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved what I needed using `gulp-postcss` along with `postcss-url`.

```
"use strict";

const Gulp = require("gulp");
const GulpRename = require("gulp-rename");
const GulpPostCSS = require("gulp-postcss");
const PostCSSImport = require("postcss-import");
const PostCSSURL = require("postcss-url");

Gulp.task("css", function() {
    return Gulp
    .src("./assets/css/index.css")
    .pipe(
        GulpPostCSS([
            PostCSSImport(),
            PostCSSURL({
                url: "copy",
                useHash: true
            })
        ], {
            from: "./assets/css/index.css",
            to: "./public/bundle.css"
        })
    )
    .pipe(GulpRename("bundle.css"))
    .pipe(Gulp.dest("./public/"));
});
```

It is also possible to do this entirely without Gulp, only with `postcss-cli`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build:css": "postcss ./assets/css/index.css --use postcss-import --use postcss-url --postcss-url.url 'copy' --postcss-url.useHash true --output ./public/bundle.css"
},
```